# react native unable to hide my drawer menu behind my screens

Tags: react-native

I tried to use transition for opening and closing my drawer but there is a problem which is my drawer is over my screen which is not satisfying. I want my screens become over my drawer.
you can clearly see below (right one is desired and left is what I achieved so far):

[image]
[image: this is the goal]

I tried to use `zIndex` on my styles but no luck. here is my navigation code:

```
const IntroStack = createStackNavigator();

const IntroNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <IntroStack.Navigator>
        <IntroStack.Screen name='intro' component={Intro} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <IntroStack.Screen name='login' component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <IntroStack.Screen name='createAccount' component={CreateAccount} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <IntroStack.Screen name='forgotPassword' component={ForgotPassword} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <IntroStack.Screen name='enterCode' component={EnterCode} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <IntroStack.Screen name='changePassword' component={ChangePassword} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <IntroStack.Screen name='home' component={DrawerNavigation} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <IntroStack.Screen name='notfications' component={Notifications} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
      </IntroStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigation = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const rotate = Animated.interpolate(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, -0.28],
  });

  const scale = Animated.interpolate(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.8],
  });

  const screenStyles = { transform: [{ rotate, scale }] }

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerType='slide' drawerStyle={{width: 300}} overlayColor='transparent' sceneContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#3170FF'}}  drawerContent={
      (props) => {
        setProgress(props.progress);
        return <DrawerContent {...props} />
      }}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home">
        {(props) => <TabNavigation style={screenStyles} />}
      </Drawer.Screen>
    </Drawer.Navigator>

  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabNavigation = (props) => {

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[{ flex: 1 }, props.style]}>
      <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
        style: {
          borderTopLeftRadius: 23,
          borderTopRightRadius: 23,
          height: 70,
          alignItems: 'center',
        }
      }} >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <TabComponent label='home' {...props} />,
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="WorldTour" component={WorldTour} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <TabComponent label='earth' {...props} />,
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Outlet" component={Outlet} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <TabComponent label='compass' {...props} />,
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="ChrisLeong" component={ChrisLeong} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <TabComponent label='crown' {...props} />,
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="OurTherapists" component={OurTherapists} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <TabComponent label='joint' {...props} />,
        }} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </Animated.View>
  );
}

export default IntroNavigation;
```

how can I fix this issue? thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you achieved the same thing? I'm trying to do it but getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Somehow i achieved it but not eactly same as required]

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {useDrawerProgress} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Animated, {interpolate, useAnimatedStyle} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {AppStyle} from '../../theme';

export default function DrawerScreen({children, style}) {
  const drawerProgress = useDrawerProgress();

  const viewStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const scale = interpolate(drawerProgress.value, [0, 1], [1, 0.75]);
    const translateX = interpolate(drawerProgress.value, [0, 1], [0, 60]);
    const borderRadius = interpolate(drawerProgress.value, [0, 1], [1, 10]);
    const rotate = interpolate(drawerProgress.value, [0, 1], [0, -12]);
    return {
      transform: [
        {scale},
        {translateX},
        {translateY: translateX - 100},
        {rotate: `${rotate}deg`},
      ],
      borderRadius,
    };
  });

  const cardStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const translateTransparentCard = interpolate(
      drawerProgress.value,
      [0, 0.4, 1],
      [0, 0, 0],
    );

    const scale = interpolate(drawerProgress.value, [0, 1], [1, 0.6]);

    const rotate = interpolate(drawerProgress.value, [0, 1], [0, -18]);
    return {
      transform: [
        {translateX: -translateTransparentCard},
        {translateY: translateTransparentCard + 20},
        {scale},
        {rotate: `${rotate}deg`},
      ],
    };
  });
  return (
    <View style={AppStyle.fill}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          {
            opacity: 0.8,
            borderRadius: 10,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            position: 'absolute',
          },
          AppStyle.fullSize,
          cardStyles,
          style,
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Animated.View>
      <Animated.View style={[style, viewStyles]}>
        <View style={[AppStyle.hideOverFlow, AppStyle.fill]}>{children}</View>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using react navigation, you can use `drawerType: "slide"` in your drawer configuration

That is available on react-navigation above v3.x and should achieve what you're expecting.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawertype

Comment: Yes, I already implemented. but unfortunately doesn't solve.

Comment: Have you tried the 'back' property in the drawerType?

Comment: Not working tried same